# History of sackcloth and ashes?

Tags: penance

I had always considered that the wearing of sackcloth and ashes was a particularly a Hebrew penance tradition. In Jonah the Ninevites, who were decidedly not Hebrew, wore sack cloth and ashes per the kings order. The King of Nineveh was not Hebrew either. So how did this decision to wear sackcloth and ashes as a symbol of penance occur so readily to the Ninevites?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

**History of sackcloth and ashes?**

The custom of the three elements, fasting, sackcloth and ashes, are an ancient eastern custom to show humiliation and repentance. It was neither invented nor originated by the Israelites but was common in the ancient east. In fact the custom of changing the dress in token of mourning was not confined to the Hebrews. The whole of antiquity shared in this tendency.

It seems that the whole of antiquity practiced penances or mourning in this way and was not a tradition that came from the Hebrew nation.

Could not the skins God gave to Adam and Eve be simply sackcloth or as some would say  hairshirt imposed on them to do penance for their sins?

In fact these ideas, even biblically speaking remount earlier than the creation of the Jewish nation and was certainly known the world over.

> Sackcloth and ashes were used in Old Testament times as a symbol of debasement, mourning, and/or repentance. Someone wanting to show his repentant heart would often wear sackcloth, sit in ashes, and put ashes on top of his head. Sackcloth was a coarse material usually made of black goat’s hair, making it quite uncomfortable to wear. The ashes signified desolation and ruin.
>
> When someone died, the act of putting on sackcloth showed heartfelt sorrow for the loss of that person. We see an example of this when David mourned the death of Abner, the commander of Saul’s army (2 Samuel 3:31). Jacob also demonstrated his grief by wearing sackcloth when he thought his son Joseph had been killed (Genesis 37:34). These instances of mourning for the dead mention sackcloth but not ashes.
>
> Ashes accompanied sackcloth in times of national disaster or repenting from sin. Esther 4:1, for instance, describes Mordecai tearing his clothes, putting on sackcloth and ashes, and walking out into the city “wailing loudly and bitterly.” This was Mordecai’s reaction to King Xerxes’ declaration giving the wicked Haman authority to destroy the Jews (see Esther 3:8–15). Mordecai was not the only one who grieved. “In every province to which the edict and order of the king came, there was great mourning among the Jews, with fasting, weeping, and wailing. Many lay in sackcloth and ashes” (Esther 4:3). The Jews responded to the devastating news concerning their race with sackcloth and ashes, showing their intense grief and distress.
>
> Sackcloth and ashes were also used as a public sign of repentance and humility before God. When Jonah declared to the people of Nineveh that God was going to destroy them for their wickedness, everyone from the king on down responded with repentance, fasting, and sackcloth and ashes (Jonah 3:5–7). They even put sackcloth on their animals (verse 8). Their reasoning was, “Who knows? God may yet relent and with compassion turn from his fierce anger so that we will not perish” (verse 9). This is interesting because the Bible never says that Jonah’s message included any mention of God’s mercy; but mercy is what they received. It’s clear that the Ninevites’ donning of sackcloth and ashes was not a meaningless show. God saw genuine change—a humble change of heart represented by the sackcloth and ashes—and it caused Him to “relent” and not bring about His plan to destroy them (Jonah 3:10).
>
> Other people the Bible mentions wearing sackcloth include King Hezekiah (Isaiah 37:1), Eliakim (2 Kings 19:2), King Ahab (1 Kings 21:27), the elders of Jerusalem (Lamentations 2:10), Daniel (Daniel 9:3), and the two witness in Revelation 11:3.
>
> Very simply, sackcloth and ashes were used as an outward sign of one’s inward condition. Such a symbol made one’s change of heart visible and demonstrated the sincerity of one’s grief and/or repentance. It was not the act of putting on sackcloth and ashes itself that moved God to intervene, but the humility that such an action demonstrated (see 1 Samuel 16:7). God’s forgiveness in response to genuine repentance is celebrated by David’s words: “You removed my sackcloth and clothed me with joy” (Psalm 30:11).
>
> - [What is the meaning of sackcloth and ashes?](https://www.gotquestions.org/sackcloth-and-ashes.html)

Sackcloth was worn as a sign of mourning and associated with ashes.

> Sackcloth is a coarsely woven fabric, usually made of goat's hair. The term in English often connotes the biblical usage, where the Hastings' Dictionary of the Bible remarks that haircloth would be more appropriate rendering of the Hebrew meaning.
>
> Hessian sackcloth or burlap is not the intended biblical meaning, according to a number of scholarly sources: but the identification represents a common misconception based on phonetic association. "Sackcloth, usually made of black goat hair, was used by the Israelites and their neighbors in times of mourning or social protest." Burlap, another term used in English translation, is also generally understood as goat haircloth. Stiff camel hair was also used.
>
> Sackcloth came to mean a garment, too, made from such cloth, which was worn as a token of mourning by the Israelites. It was also a sign of submission (1 Kings 20:31–32), or of grief and self-humiliation (2 Kings 19:1), and was occasionally worn by the Prophets. It is often associated with ashes. - [Sackcloth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sackcloth#:%7E:text=%22Sackcloth%2C%20usually%20made%20of%20black,camel%20hair%20was%20also%20used.)

Hairshirts are also considered sackcloth garments.

> The earliest hairshirts were probably the sackcloths mentioned in the Old Testament. These were rough garments worn by those in mourning. They would have made the wearer only uncomfortable, though, since self-injury through cutting is forbidden by Jewish law. Throughout centuries, hairshirts have been used by ascetics, clergy, monks, nuns, friars, and devout laypeople alike. Thomas Beckett was wearing one when he was assassinated, Thomas More wore one while he was imprisoned in the tower of London, and Charlemagne was buried in one.
>
> While hairshirts are often associated with the Middle Ages, they’re still used today by members of various Christian denominations throughout the year. During Lent, hairshirts are sometimes used as altar cloths, and small pieces of sackcloth might be given out to parishioners as a reminder that Lent is a season of repentance and piety. - [The History of Hairshirts](https://handwovenmagazine.com/history-hairshirts/#:%7E:text=The%20earliest%20hairshirts%20were%20probably,is%20forbidden%20by%20Jewish%20law.)

Even [St. John the Baptist](https://aleteia.org/2019/08/29/the-spiritual-symbolism-of-john-the-baptists-unusual-clothing/) wore garments of camel hair, thus equivalent to a hairshirt.

Ashes were often associated with mourning and penance, but again this tradition was not unique to the Hebrew people of antiquity.

> A number of passages in the Old Testament connect ashes (efer) with mourning, and we are told that the mourner sat or rolled himself in, sprinkled his head or mingled his food with, "ashes", but it is not clear whether in these passages we ought not rather to translate efer as dust. The same phrases are used with the word afar which certainly means dust. It may be that the dust was originally taken from the grave, in token that the living felt himself one with the dead, or it may be that humiliation and the neglect of personal cleanliness constituted the dominant idea; for a similar manifestation of grief was undoubtedly familiar among Aryan peoples, e.g. in Homer (Iliad, XVIII, 23). It seems less probable that the cleansing properties of ashes (though this also has been proposed) are taken as significant of moral purification. The chief foundation for this last suggestion is the Rite of the Red Heifer (Numbers 19:17) in which the ashes of the victim when mixed with water had the ceremonial efficacy of purifying the unclean (cf. Hebrews 9:13).
>
> Be this as it may, Christianity at an early date undoubtedly adopted the use of ashes as symbolical of penance. Thus Tertullian prescribes that the penitent must "live without joy in the roughness of sackcloth and the squalor of ashes" (De Pœnitentiâ, x); and many similar passages might be quoted from St. Cyprian and other early Fathers. Eusebius in his account of the apostasy and reconciliation of Natalis describes him as coming to Pope Zephyrinus clothed in sackcloth and sprinkled over with ashes (spodon katapasamenon, Church History V.28) - [Ashes](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01776c.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Sackcloth and ashes is generally considered a Hebrew practice. It is seen throughout the Old Testament when people demonstrate their grief or desire for repentance. Mordecai practices it in the book of Esther when he hears of how Haman manipulated the king to allow for the Jewish people to be killed.

However, like you point out above, sometimes cultures that are not Hebrew practice it. In Matthew 11:21, Jesus even says Tyre and Sidon would have put on sackcloth and ashes to repent if they had experienced the same miracles.

I would hazard a guess that the king either had an understanding of what the practice of the Hebrews was when it came to repentance, or that Jonah told them and it is simply not recorded. The king could have assumed that this is the Hebrew people's God and so we should do what they do to repent.

Another option (perhaps more likely) would be that a Hebrew audience reading or hearing the book of Jonah being read would have understood what sackcloth and ashes meant. So perhaps it was the easiest way for the author to communicate the king's response to a Hebrew audience.

Answer (score 0):

### Sackcloth and Ashes for Mourning

The custom of wearing sackcloth represent the highest form of mourning, it is not necessarily for repentance.

> [Esth 4:1-3 ESV] When Mordecai learned all that had been done, Mordecai tore his clothes and put on sackcloth and ashes, and went out into the midst of the city, and he cried out with a loud and bitter cry. He went up to the entrance of the king's gate, for no one was allowed to enter the king's gate clothed in sackcloth. And in every province, wherever the king's command and his decree reached, there was great mourning among the Jews, with fasting and weeping and lamenting, and many of them lay in sackcloth and ashes.

This custom was not limited to Israel, but the basic ritual purity and various funeral and mourning customs were shared by *all nations* of the world. Thus, in the ancient world it must have been practised by all the nations. As we find examples from the Chinese custom of funeral mourning involving wearing sackcloth and ashes. See *The Religious System of China, Its Ancient Forms, Evolution, History and Present Aspect, Manners, Customs and Social Institutions Connected Therewith* by [JJM de Groot, 1892](https://www.google.com/search?q=sackcloth+funeral+ancient++&tbm=bks&uact=5), pp. 13, 27.

Scene from a [Chinese drama](https://youtu.be/4ShSZjrs_6g?si=yajAcr4ifd0FPAXe&t=1886) ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Too_Late_to_Say_I_Love_You)) depicting a funeral where the family is wearing sackcloths, set in the 20th century.

[image]